# Showing progress indicator when clicking on link

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, asp.net-web-api

I have an HTML link on my page.

```
 <a id="myDownLoadlink" data-bind="attr: { href: uRlPath }" style="visibility: hidden">Get data file</a>
```

When I click on the link I call the web API service and download some files. I can't understand how can I show the progress bar while something is getting downloaded. This is how I call my web API service

```
uRlPath("/api/GetMyData?id=" + 2
                + "&name=" + name.toString());
$('#myDownLoadlink').click();

location.href = $('#linkToDownload').attr('href');
```

It could have been easy to show the progress bar if I could have used Ajax call but in my case, I can't do it due for some reason. Please let me know if there is any way out.

Comment: *Unless you use Ajax*, you cannot control the page loading. The browser is simply loading a new page and the old one is ignored/discarded. The only solution is to use Ajax calls (then you can have progress, transitions etc).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Is there no way at all apart from Ajax? There should be some way. We didnt had Ajax in old days. Please check if something can be done. I really need it. I will be extremely thankful to you

Comment: In the "old days" you could not do it either without Ajax. Ajax has been around for a long time. *Why* can't you use Ajax/jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie so then you say its impossible

Comment: I like to think that *nothing is impossible*, but many things are just *impractical*. For instance, you *could* write a custom web-browser (but you wouldn't) :) Just use Ajax... it's very easy.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i couldnt use Ajax was because it was somehow corrupting my file when i downloaded it. I tried a lot but couldnt solve it. So thats why i use this method to download data.

Comment: You should be asking about the *file corruption* instead as *you* have incorrectly setup either the request or the response. Ajax does not just corrupt data for no reason! :)

Comment: Do you have access to the server? There is a solution without ajax but you need access to the place serving the file to give some kind of complete callback.

Comment: @LanderVanBreda yes i have access. Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have server access you can try to do this. 
A Little explanation. You should load the download link inside a iFrame. The download will then start but because the browser will not give a onload callback when the loaded url is an attachment, we need a server workaround.

The workaround will need you to send a token to the backend. Then when you send the file back you will have to set the client's cookie to this value with this response.

The cookie param should be called downloadtoken. The code will check every 200 seconds if this cookie is set. Which will only be set when  the pageload is complete aka when you file is in.

Have fun .

```
function getCookie( name ) {
    var parts = document.cookie.split(name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function expireCookie( cName ) {
    document.cookie = 
      encodeURIComponent( cName ) +
      "=deleted; expires=" +
      new Date( 0 ).toUTCString();
}



var downloadFile = function(url,completeCallback){
    var downloadToken = new Date().getTime();
    iframe  = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);



    iframe.src = url + '&downloadtoken=' +downloadToken;

    var checkServerFeedback = function(){
        var outcome = getCookie('downloadtoken');
        if(downloadtoken == outcome){
            expireCookie('downloadtoken');
            completeCallback();
        }
        setTimeout(checkServerFeedback,200);
    };
    setTimeout(checkServerFeedback,200);
};



/**
    Start of app code
**/
console.log('Add loader here');
downloadFile('http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.2.0.zip',function(){
    console.log('The file has been downloaded remove loader here.');
});
```

Comment: Didnt understood what i should return from service and what i need to send to backend. if you see my url i send 2 parameters. Do u mean i send something more? I send response back as HttpResponseMessage.

Comment: iframe.src = url + '&downloadtoken=' +downloadToken; Is the thing sending the token to the backend, you should read this token on the backend. And set it as a cookie.

Comment: But from backend i return HttpResponseMessage,so how can i set it as cookie? DO you have any example of this?

Comment: How your backend works is unique to your language/framework. It won't be a copy paste solution for this. It is one of the most basic principles of web development and shall be easily available on google.

Comment: Happy I can not provide you an example read my comment , it is totally depending on your language/framework.

Comment: couple of questions. 1) what i need to pass to completecallback 2. Where to set progress bar as i cant see anywhere progress bar in your code

Comment: @Happy this is not google, search a bit and come with constructive questions... really.

Comment: Can you answer me some question from your code you posted? I am now returning cookie from my WEBAPI called downloadtoken. I have used exact code as you have posted. But when i put breakpoint on line "console.log('The file has been downloaded remove loader here.');", it keeps on looping there. Also i get undefined in outcome variable. Can you tell what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Happy there was a typo in the code it should be downloadtoken==outcome.

Comment: But anyway i get undefined. My service is returning me cookie though

Comment: If you are interested in getting bounty then do answer my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680845/download-file-without-using-ajax