# download file without using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to follow this [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx) to show progress bar without using ajax to download file.

I use knockout,html and webapi. I am having below code which calls href on click event of button

```
this.getMeData= function () {

    uRlPath("/api/GetSomeData?id=" + 12)
                + "&name=" + getName.toString()
                + "&downloadtoken=" + new Date().getTime());

    $('#myLink').click();

    location.href = $('#myLink').attr('href');


    };
```

This is my html

```
   <tr>
            <td class="labelText">
                <button data-bind="click: getMeData">
                   Download Data
                </button>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <a id="myLink" data-bind="attr: { href: uRlPath }" style="visibility: hidden">Open </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I now want to call some function on click event of my href

This is my webapi method which returns me cookie and binary file

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetSomeData(int id, string name, string downloadtoken)
    {
      var returnData= new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      returnData.Content = new ByteArrayContent(mybyteArray);
       var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("downloadtoken", downloadtoken);
        returnData.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
      returnData.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        returnData.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");


        returnData.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myfile.pdf";
        return returnData;
    }
```

To be very precise i want to have same behaviour as provided in example. In example they use form to submit but i dont have any form as i just use html,knockout. I have included all libraries mentioned in example.

Do let me know if you need more inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself. I used below code to check constantly for cookie

```
var attempts = 30;
var checkTime

        startProgressBar(true)

        checkTime= window.setInterval(function () {

            var cookieValue = $.cookie('downloadtoken');

            if ((cookieValue == token) || (attempts == 0)){
                 stopDownload();
            }
            attempts --;
        }, 1000);
```

In `finishDownload` function i clear cookie and stop progress bar

```
 function stopDownload() {
        window.clearInterval(checkTime);
        $.cookie('downloadtoken', null); //clears this cookie value
        stopProgressBar(false);
    }
```

This is html code for progress bar

```
 <div  data-bind="visible: stopProgressBar" style="top:248px;left: 320px;">
    <img src="../images/ProgressBar.jpg"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call the blockUIForDownload function when the link is clicked, you can do it with a "click" binding, just like you did for the button:

```
<a id="myLink" data-bind="attr: {href: uRlPath}, click: blockUIForDownload" style="visibility: hidden">Open</a>
```

(This assumes the function is already defined within the viewModel.)

See official documentation for the "click" binding here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

However, it looks to me like you're overcomplicating it a bit - in the example you posted, a hidden input field is required because they're using a form input as a means to transfer the token to the server.

In your case the token is passed as a part of an href attribute, so you can greatly simplify the code:

1) Remove the invisible link completely

2) Replace the getMeData function with the following:

```
this.getMeData= function () {
    window.open("/api/GetSomeData?id=" + 12
                + "&name=" + getName.toString()
                + "&downloadtoken=" + new Date().getTime());
    blockUIForDownload();
    };
```

Comment: I need same kind of mechanism as provided in example. In example they used form to submit and i dont have any form to submit as i use knockout and html. What i want is to call webapi service on button. This service returns me pdf file. So what i want is to show some progress bar or something until file is downloaded. Did you referred example i provided? Also i cant use window.open as it opens new window.